# Call function on Dataframe's columns has error TypeError: Column is not iterable

Tags: pyspark, null, azure-databricks

I am using Databricks with Spark 2.4. and i am coding Python

I have created this function to convert null to empty string

```
def xstr(s):
    if s is None:
        return ""
    return str(s)
```

Then I have below code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

lv_query = """
  SELECT 
    SK_ID_Site, Designation_Site
  FROM db_xxx.t_xxx 
  ORDER BY SK_ID_Site 
  limit 2"""
lvResult = spark.sql(lv_query)

a = lvResult1.select(map(xstr, col("Designation_Site")))

display(a)
```

I have this error : `TypeError: Column is not iterable`

what i need to do here is to call a function for each row that i have in my Dataframe. i would like to pass columns as parameters and have a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how spark works. You cannot apply direct python code to a spark dataframe content.
There are already builtin functions that do the job for you.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

a = lvResult1.select(
    F.when(F.col("Designation_Site").isNull(), "").otherwise(
        F.col("Designation_Site").cast("string")
    )
)
```

In case you want some more complex functions that you cannot do with the builtin functions, you can use an UDF but it may impact a lot your performances (better check for existing builtin functions before building your own UDF).